# I tried updating info in an answer but the suggested edit got rejected

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

This is the edited answer I'm referring to: https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/68397

What should I do in this case? Posting the up-to-date solution in a separate answer?

Comment: Or, you know... comment ;)

Answer (score 6):

As one of the rejecters: yes, it would have been appropriate to post a new answer *with your rationale for the changes*.

Introducing that much new information without the original author's involvement (through commenting) would have changed their intent, as per our editing guidelines.

Comment: +1 (I was the other person rejecting)